# Signing out from Hangouts Webapp in Chrome Linux version

Tags: google-chrome, webapps, chrome-extension

Recently I installed Chrome v27 in my Ubuntu 13.04 (32 bit) Desktop OS.

Then installed few extensions, one of them is "Hangouts" for Chrome WebApp...

In my Windows version of Chrome App, I am able to "Signout" from the Hangouts extension, but in my Linux Version of Chrome I'm not able to do so. I had to remove it if I want to signout.

Anyone facing this behaviour like me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just installed Hangouts into Chrome just to test your question. There is a little down arrow next to the "+ New Hangout" button that will allow you to sign out.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Githlar, I've not noticed that I can actually increase the height of Hangouts window.